# Cannot create Server Object in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have just started setting up an existing project in classic asp on my local environment and I am stuck getting this error

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
> Server.CreateObject Failed

The line where I am getting the error is as follows:

```
Server.CreateObject("WebCache.SqlStream")
```

I am using IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the ProgId `WebCache.SqlStream` is not registered with COM, this can happen for a number of reasons.

- The most common reason is the DLL file associated with the COM component is not registered on the server this can be done using the `regsvr32.exe "fullpath\dllname.dll"`
- The DLL file is registered but has been moved or there is a permission issue (usually in relation to reading the corresponding registry keys).
- The system is `x64` architecture and the ASP application is running in `32-bit mode` in the application pool. What happens in this scenario is the DLL is registered using the 64 bit version of `regsvr32.exe` this places the ProgId into the 64 bit registry hive. To fix this you need to run the 32 bit version of `regsvr32.exe`. In 64 bit Windows Server Operating systems and Windows Vista (or above) it can be found in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` which contains 32 bit equivalents of Windows system files.

There is also some useful information about what to check in this Microsoft Support Article - [PRB: Server Object Error 'ASP 0177:80040154' Server.CreateObject](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175804)

Comment: Hi, I have searched "WebCache.SqlStream" in windows registry but did not found any entry for same. Can you please tell me which dll I should register in window ?

Comment: @user3030342 Where did this component come from? Surely you have the DLL for it? Only reference I can find in google is to an old ASP site someone has left completely exposed to public but removing the ASP ISAPI filter - http://www.damsinc.com/old_site/index.asp it appears to be some kind of caching component but other then that I don't know.

Comment: @user3030342 Only references I can find are in the ASP code to this site Google Search [site:www.damsinc.com filetype:asp](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&es_sm=93&q=site%3Awww.damsinc.com+filetype%3Aasp&oq=site%3Awww.damsinc.com+filetype%3Aasp&gs_l=serp.3...35251.52442.0.53551.33.33.0.0.0.0.173.4150.8j25.33.0....0...1c.1.43.serp..29.4.382.Ab1SygGF8JA#q=site:www.damsinc.com+filetype:asp&safe=off)

Comment: @user3030342 My guess would be this is a bespoke component that was built for the purpose of caching, if you don't have access to the DLL I'm afraid your pretty much stuck, unless you can trace the original owner of the code you are using.

Comment: Sorry Guys, It was a third party DLL which was not registered in my registry. Thanks for all of your precious support.